# Connect to server from PhoneGap

Tags: php, android, phonegap

I am using PhoneGap to convert my HTML project into an Android app. However, every time the HTML page has a reference to some php file (eg : action="/login.php"> ) PhoneGap refuses to open it. Right now I am running it on xampp local server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use absolute URLs instead of relative.
Using `/login.php` url means *same origin as current page plus* `/login.php`. So if your web site was `www.example.com`. then `/login.php` would point to `www.example.com/login.php`.
But while it is running in `PhoneGap`, origin is something like `android_asset`, and there is no `/login.php` for sure.

So instead of `action="/login.php"` you have to use full URL: `action="www.your_site.com/login.php"`